# Коллекции моделей в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Привет. Меня интересует вопрос по моделях. На моих моделях висит бизнес-логика, и в самих объектах есть состояния, то есть есть поля с данными и методы и когда я создаю модель, мне нужно провести инициализацию. Я думал делать их через конструктор, но почему то у меня были ошибки, уже не помню какие, это было давно, я решил сделать метод init(), и получается где то так `$user = User(); $user->init($id)`. И теперь вопрос,  когда я хочу использовать коллекции, например  `$users = User::all()`, есть ли способ, как нибудь их проинициализировать, более красиво, чем просто через цикл?

Answer (score 2):

Проблемы с конструктором были скорее всего потому, что вы не добавили в него

```
parent::_construct()
```

И все должно работать. Модель прекрасно экстендиться. В данном случае, `$user->init($id)` - это костыль, а практически любое решение с костылем - будет костыль костыля)) Так что настраивайте инициализацию класса.
Но я бы лично посоветовал использовать `$casts` или если не устраивает `$casts`, можно использовать произвольный класс коллекции со своими свойствами и методами.